PL SQL function call having return as boolean gives error
I am getting this error

ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
*Cause:
*Action: Error at Line: 24 Column: 5

When I run the following code:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_func_s (
    val IN NUMBER
) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
BEGIN
    IF val IS NOT NULL THEN
        RETURN TRUE;
    END IF;
END;
/

SELECT
    CHECK_FUNC_S(1) 
FROM
    DUAL ;

Please advise how to make it work.

Boolean values can only be used in PL/SQL layer, not in SQL.
So If you want this function to return value using a 'select from dual' statement, then you will need to re-define the function to return varchar2 with the return values 'true' or 'false'.
So in your case
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_func_s (
    val IN NUMBER
) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
    IF val IS NOT NULL THEN
        RETURN 'True';
    ELSE RETURN 'False';
    END IF;
END;

Note: With the new version of Oracle Database, you can now use it with Boolean. However, if you have older versions of DB, you still need your funtion to return varchar.
Source: ORACLE

With the same code I written where return function is Boolean I am trying to call like this BEGIN
EXEC CHECK_FUNC_S(1)  ;
END ;
this even throws error , please guide for correct call

If you want to use BEGIN END; syntax, define it as procedure. If you want to call it using select check_func_s(1) from dual; then it is returning 'True' with the function definition I provided in the answer.

Thank you .. will check out creating procedure.Hope it works for me
